# Probability of signal malfunctioning the same way

Tags: probability, binomial-distribution, bernoulli-distribution

I'm writing a paper for computer networks and came across the problem of calculating the probability that a certain event happens:

**Problem**:

I have two wires, each transmitting one bit of information at a time. Each wire can malfunction and send the wrong bit with the probability of p. if the two wires transmit 32 times, what are the chances that the two wires malfunctioned **the same way** (eg, a malfunction occurs on both wires at the same time)?

**Thinking Process**

I was thinking:

Take the first transmission, let X be whether a malfunction occured for wire 1, and Y be weather it happened for wire 2. Then, X and Y follow a bernoulli rv.

P(malfunction happened for both wires for the first bit) = p^2

Now im stuck, as how would I take into account all possibilities for this? I was thinking a binobial rv, but binomials are order independent when this is order dependent.

I was also thinking:

P(1 malfunction happened in the 2 wires) * 32 + P(2 malfunctions happened * 32C2) etc but I'm again, unsure of this as well

Thank you humbly for your help! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right track.

Let's say $X_i$ is an indicator random variable for whether the first wire malfunctions on the $i^{th}$ bit where $X_i = 1$ means a malfunction and $X_i = 0$ means not a malfunction. Let $Y_i$ be the same thing for the second wire. What you ultimately want to calculate is $P(X_1 = Y_1 \wedge X_2 = Y_2 \wedge ... \wedge X_{32} = Y_{32})$.

I'm going to assume that $X_1, ..., X_{32}, Y_1, ..., Y_{32} \sim Ber(p)$ are all IID. The problem doesn't explicitly state this, but it seems to imply it, and we can't find a specific answer without this assumption anyway.

Using that the variables are IID:
$P(X_1 = Y_1 \wedge X_2 = Y_2 \wedge ... \wedge X_{32} = Y_{32}) = \prod_{i=1}^{32}P(X_i = Y_i) = P(X_1 = Y_1)^{32}$. Now we need to calculate $P(X_1 = Y_1)$.

$P(X_1 = Y_1)$ is the probability that both wires malfunction or both wires don't malfunction in the first bit. We can calculate this as follows:
$P(X_1 = Y_1) = P(X_1 = Y_1 = 1) + P(X_1 = Y_1 = 0) = P(X_1 = 1)P(Y_1 = 1) + P(X_1 = 0)P(Y_1 = 0) = p^2 + (1 - p)^2$.

Thus, putting this back into the above, the probability that the two wires  malfunction in the same way over all 32 bits is $(p^2 + (1-p)^2))^{32}$.

Comment: you know they say computer science is hard, I'd say statistics is harder. Thanks! :)